# Scrapy not giving individual results of all the reviews of a phone?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

This code is giving me results but the output is not as desired .what is wrong with my xpath? How to iterate the rule by +10. I have problem in these two always.

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name_reviewer = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    model_name = scrapy.Field()
    rating = scrapy.Field()
    review = scrapy.Field()



class criticspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "flip_review"
    allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]

    start_urls = ['http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/product-reviews/ITME5Z9GKXGMFSF6?pid=MOBDUUDTADHVQZXG&type=all']
    rules = (
        Rule(
            SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*\&start=.*',)),
            callback="parse_start_url",
            follow=True),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        sites = response.css('div.review-list div[review-id]')
        items = []
        model_name = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').re(r'Reviews of (.*?)$')
        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['model_name'] = model_name
            item['name_reviewer'] = ''.join(site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]//text()').extract())
            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/text()').extract()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"line fk-font-normal bmargin5 dark-gray")]/strong/text()').extract()
            item['review'] = site.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"review-text")]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

My output is:

```
 {'date': [u'\n 31 Mar 2015 ', u'\n 23 Mar 2015 '],
  'model_name': [u'\n Reviews of A & K 333 '],
  'name_reviewer': [u'\n pradeep kumar', u'\n vikas agrawal']}
```

and I want my output to be :

```
{model_name :xyz
name_reviewer :abc
date:38383
}
{model_name :xyz
name_reviewer :hfhd
date:9283
}
```

I think the problem is with my XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your XPath expressions are very *fragile* in general.

The main problem with your approach is that `site` does not contain a review section, but it should. In other words, you are not iterating over review blocks on a page.

Also, the model name should be extracted outside of a loop since it is the same for every review on a page. I would also use `.re()` to extract the model name out of the title, e.g. `SAMSUNG GALAXY S5` out of `REVIEWS OF SAMSUNG GALAXY S5`.

Here is the complete working code with fixes applied:

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    sites = response.css('div.review-list div[review-id]')

    model_name = response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').re(r'Reviews of (.*?)$')[0].strip()
    for site in sites:
        item = CompItem()
        item['model_name'] = model_name
        item['name_reviewer'] = ''.join(site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]//text()').extract()).strip()
        item['date'] = site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "date")]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        yield item
```

The XPath expressions are also made simpler. For the sake of an example, the review sections are identified by a CSS selector `div.review-list div[review-id]` that would match all `div` elements containing `review-id` attribute anywhere under the `div` having `review-list` class.

Also, note how `name_reviewer` is extracted - since there are different users, some of them are represented as a profile link, some are not registered and are located in the `span` with `review-username` class - I've taken a different approach: locating the review date and getting the first preceding sibling's text.

---

I'd like to point out that class names like `line`, `fk-font-small`, `fk-font-11` etc are layout-oriented classes and are, generally speaking, not a good choice to rely your XPath expressions and CSS selectors on. Note, what classes are used to locate elements in the answer: `review-list`, `title`, `date` - they are more data-oriented and a better choice for your locators.

Comment: I always find xpath thing very difficult how to deal with it everytime?

Comment: Hey @alecxe there is one problem I am able to see data being extracted on shell but when I print the output in a csv file it comes blank why?

Comment: @JohnDene I've added some more improvements to the code. Now when I run the spider as, for example, `scrapy runspider spider1.py -t csv -o output.csv` I'm getting the extracted data in the `output.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

this should help, its the problem with your `xpath`,

```
In [1]: data_list = []

In [2]: sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="review-list"]/div')

In [3]: for site in sites:
    data = {}
    data['name_reviewer'] = site.xpath('./div/div[@class="line"]/span[@class="fk-color-title fk-font-11 review-username"]/text()|./div/div[@class="line"]/a[@class="load-user-widget fk-underline"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    data['date'] = site.xpath('./div/div[@class="date line fk-font-small"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    data['model_name'] =  response.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
    data_list.append(data)


In [4]: data_list
Out[4]: 
[{'date': u'10 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'RISHABH GROVER'},
 {'date': u'11 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Hemraj Chaudhari'},
 {'date': u'28 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'RISHABH GROVER'},
 {'date': u'27 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Debadutta Patnaik'},
 {'date': u'24 May 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Joel'},
 {'date': u'11 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Saswat Nayak'},
 {'date': u'14 Apr 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Amit Thakor'},
 {'date': u'28 May 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Nishchal Sharma'},
 {'date': u'13 May 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'siddiq hassan'},
 {'date': u'16 May 2014',
  'model_name': u'Reviews of Samsung Galaxy S5',
  'name_reviewer': u'Raja Shekhar'}]
```

Comment: Thanx jitin but getting error str object has no attribute extract

Comment: where are you getting that error ? Could you paste  the complete error code  or at least the erroneous line ?

Comment: May be I am using the rule that's why it is throwing this error